# Drop Down not even showing up in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, drop-down-menu

I've got a drop down menu here that just plain won't show up in IE6.  The site works perfectly in every other browser.  Seems daft to lose sleep over IE6, I know, but the site is for a demographic who could very well still be using it.

Here's the CSS:

```
html {
    height:100%;
}

body, p, a, ul, li, ol, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    behavior:url("csshover3.htc");
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    height:100%;
}

h1 {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#752eca;
    text-decoration:none;
}

h2 {
    font-size:14px;
    color:#909090;
    text-decoration:none!important;
}

p {
    text-indent:20px;
    color:#000;
}

p a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

p.foot {
    text-indent:0px;
}

p.link {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#30F;
    text-decoration:underline!important;
}

a {
    color:#4d2288;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
}

a:visited {
    color:#4d2288;
}

p a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline!important;
}

ul#nav {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:100%;
}

ul#nav li a {
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:2px 10px;
    background:#bacddb;
}

ul#nav li a:hover {
    background:#888;
    color:#fff;
}

li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:225px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px auto;
    margin-right:4px;
    border:1px solid #4d2288;
}

li ul {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin-left:-1px;
}

li>ul {
    top:auto;
    left:auto;
    border-top:none;
}

li:hover ul, li.over ul {
    display:block;
}

ul#nav li.current a {
    background:#b8ab28;
}

ul#nav li.current a:hover {
    background:#888;
}

img {
    margin:10px 0 5px;
}

*html img {
    margin:20px;
}

.coltextimg {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background-position:left bottom;
    padding:0px 20px 10px 0px;
    border:none;
}

#maincontent {
    width:940px;
    margin:0px auto;
    postition:absolute;
}

*html #maincontent {
    margin-left:42px;
}

#header {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:auto!important;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-image:url(images/banner_test.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:2px solid #752eca;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:10px;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
}

.colmask {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:160px;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.colright,
.colmid {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.col1,
.col2 {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px 0 1em 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.twocol {
    background:#fff;
}

.twocol .colmid {
    right:45%;
    background:#fff;
}

.twocol .col1 {
    width:51%;
    left:47%;
    text-align:justify;
    z-index:0;
}

.twocol .col2 {
    width:41%;
    left:51%;
    text-align:justify;
    z-index:0;
}

.twocol .colimg {
    border:2px solid #a0a0a0;
}

.twocol .colvid1 {
    width:360px;
    height:240px;
}

.twocol .colvid2 {
    width:360px;
    height:240px;
}

#footer {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:9px;
    padding:10px 0 1em 0;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

*html #footer {
    height:43px;
}

#footer p a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#lyr_ddmenu {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    height:10px;
    top:120px;
    float:left;
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:5px;
}

#contact {
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    font-size:10px;
}

A.Controls:link {
    color:#666666;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}

A.Controls:visited {
    color:#666666;
    text-decoration:none; 
    font-weight:bold;
}

A.Controls:active {
    color:#666666;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}

A.Controls:hover {
    color:#be0000;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

And here's the html I'm having the specific problem with:

```
<div id="maincontent">
<div id="header">
    <div id="lyr_ddmenu">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li class="current"><href here...</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><href here...</a></li>
            <li><href here...</a></li>
            <li><href here...</a></li>
            <li><href here...</a></li>
            <li><href here...</a></li>
        </ul></li>
            <li><href here...</a></li>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><href here...</a></li>
            <li><href here...</a></li>
            <li><href here...</a></li>
            <li><href here...</a></li>
        </ul></li>
            <li><href here...</a></li>
            <li><href here...</a></li>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><href here...</a></li>
        </ul></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Remove `behavior:url("csshover3.htc");` from the `body`

2) Add this to the bottom (better replacement of the `.htc`)

```
* html li { scrollbar-face-color: expression(runtimeStyle.scrollbarFaceColor = '#fff', onmouseover = function() {this.className += ' hover'}, onmouseout = function() {this.className = this.className.replace(/ hover/g, '')} ); }
    li.hover ul { display:block; } /* (li:hover) */
```

3) Should work.

---

**or try to separate**

```
li:hover ul { display:block; }
li.over ul { display:block; }
```

---

You can also **use jQuery** to handle `:hover`

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("li").bind('mouseover mouseout',function(){$(this).toggleClass('hover')});
});
```

play around `.hover` class:

```
li.hover ul { _display: block; } /* Styles for IE6 */
```

Comment: Thanks, much cleaner, but still can't even see the drop down in ie6.  Is this a stack order bug?  As I said, everything else looks and works fine in every other browser...

Comment: hmm...still not there.  Really considering just not caring, with >8% using IE6...

Answer (score 3):

IE6 does not support the `:hover` pseudo-class for all elements, only `a` tags, so the following rule will not get applied in IE6:

```
li:hover ul, li.over ul {
    display:block;
}
```

It looks like your menus are designed to use Javascript to emulate `:hover` by adding the class `over` to the `li` elements using the `mouseover` functions, so you'll need to post any Javascript before anyone can diagnose what's going on in IE6.

Just on the off chance that this might help, you can use the [Whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html) script to emulate this behavior in IE6.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.

"Just on the off chance that this might help, you can use the Whatever:hover  script to emulate this behavior in IE6."

body {
    behavior:url("csshover3.htc");
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    height:100%;
}

I believe I'm utilizing this correctly here, but perhaps no.  I will check into trying to apply :hover to my lists manually.  Do you know of a way to do this using the *html hack?

Also...no js for the drop down...I've removed the .over class, not sure why that was there!  Thanks.

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't even see that was in your `body` class. My guess is that maybe the url to the .htc file or something else with the script is wrong. Remember, the url in your css file is relative to the css file. Also, instead of using hacks like *html, I suggest using conditional comments to include a stylesheet only for IE6 with the hack. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx